# How to use Bootstrap 5 (RTL or LTR) based on Locale on a multilingual website?

Tags: laravel, locale, bootstrap-5

I am planning to develop a multilingual website by Laravel 8 and Bootstrap 5. As you know, Bootstrap in version 5 has an LTR version and an RTL version. How to use the LTR version of Bootstrap when the language of the website is left to right (for example, English) and the RTL version of Bootstrap when the language of the website is right to left (for example, Persian or Arabic)?

Is it possible if I want to do this in Laravel mix?

Answer (score 3):

The [Bootstrap 5 docs](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/getting-started/rtl/) explain how to support RTL.

Basically you need to:

1. Add the appropriate lang attribute, for example `lang="ar"`, and the direction `dir="rtl"` in the HTML element.
2. Include an RTL version of Bootstrap: `<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta2/dist/css/bootstrap.rtl.min.css"`

On the Laravel side you need to explore some of the techniques in the Laravel community. I suggest you start with the [Laravel Localization docs](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/localization).

I suggest one of the ways to do so would be defining the HTML direction with a few `App` object function calls, for example:

```html
<html lang="{{App::getLocale()}}" dir="{{(App::isLocale('ar') ? 'rtl' : 'ltr')}}">
```